# what will happen to the distribution of electrons in real space if the electrons in K-space are transferred from k=0 to k not equal to 0?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory

Many semiconductors like GaAs, their conduction band has more than one valley in the first brillouin zone, so a case is that when electron energy is enough, electrons can transfer from the lowest energy valley to the second lowest energy valley which is referred to Gunn effect. However, such transfer will bring electrons a non-zero crystal momentum. my question will such a non-zero crystal momentum re-distribute the electrons in the real space? If not, how could the electrons with non-zero crystal momentum still uniformly be distributed in the real space? [image]
look this figure shows the many valley system in GaAs